gtsummary: format digits with comma instead dot
The dots of my numeric values in the tbl_summary table were not all changeable into commas. Only p-values were displayed with a comma. However, all other descriptive statistics and the missing values were yet shown with a dot.
I converted the tbl table into a gt table with as_gt, then added this:
` fmt_number(columns = everything(),
decimals = 2,
dec_mark = ",",
sep_mark = ".")`

Only the p-values appeared with a comma.
Second approach:
  fmt_number(
    columns = starts_with("stat_"),
    decimals = 2,
    dec_mark = ",",
    sep_mark = ".") %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = matches("p.value|p_val"), 
    decimals = 3,
    dec_mark = ",",
    sep_mark = ".") %>%
  fmt(
    columns = everything(),
    rows = contains("Missing Values"),
    fns = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",") )

Again, only the p-values were shown with a comma. For the other statistics, nothing changed.
How can I changes all dots into a comma?

Provide example input data, dput(mydata)

The simplest way to accomplish this for gtsummary tables is by setting a language theme. In the example below, I switched to "es" but you can also keep "en".
library(gtsummary)

# change the language to spanish and the default big.mark and decimal.mark
theme_gtsummary_language("es", big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
#> Setting theme "language: es"

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    include = c(marker, response),
    missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  add_difference() |> 
  as_kable()




Característica
Drug A N = 98
Drug B N = 102
Difference
95% CI
p-valor




Marker Level (ng/mL)
0,84 (0,23 – 1,60)
0,52 (0,18 – 1,21)
0,20
-0,05 – 0,44
0,12


Tumor Response
28 (29%)
33 (34%)
-4,2%
-18% – 9,9%
0,6



Created on 2024-12-04 with reprex v2.1.1
